# Which is the best way to execute Select query and fetch results using Prepared statement among these?

Tags: php, select, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am confused among these methods of executing a select query can anyone help differentiate among these methods and explain which is better among these.

1st method

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
// do something with $row
}
```

2nd method

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->query('SELECT * FROM employees');

while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

3rd method

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {
$stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($district);
$stmt->fetch();

printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);
```

Answer (score 1):

All three serve for different purposes

- the first one is used to get multiple results from a prepared statement. note that this behavior is not guaranteed.
- the second one is used to get multiple results without a prepared statement
- the third one is used to get a single result from a prepared statement

From all this you can tell that the best method to execute Select query and fetch results using Prepared statement would be using **PDO:**

getting multiple results from a prepared statement

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->execute([$name]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

getting multiple results without a prepared statement

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->query('SELECT * FROM employees');
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

getting a single result from a prepared statement

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?"));
$stmt->execute([$city]);
$district = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

You see, all the methods are *uniform*, less verbose and guaranteed to work. I've got a pretty nice [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) which I highly recommend.